# Create a square progressBar with Transparent Background in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, progress-bar

Hello to All react Native developers!

I am new to React Native.
and i didn't know how to create a square Progress-Bar.

Is there any way to create a square Progress-Bar with transparent background in React Native?
my requirement is that, i want to create a progress-Bar around a QR Code, and you already know that the QR Code is Square.

Please! Any one help me.......

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're going to want is to wrap the QR code with 2 separate layered Views and fill in the top layered one similar to the standard methods for circular progress bars using whatever your progress metric is to define the radius of the fill.

[https://www.dottedsquirrel.com/circular-progress-css/#:~:text=Circular%20progress%20bars%20are%20a%20staple%20of%20web%20development.&text=While%20it's%20easy%20to%20cheat,bar%20with%20a%20percentage%20progression](https://www.dottedsquirrel.com/circular-progress-css/#:%7E:text=Circular%20progress%20bars%20are%20a%20staple%20of%20web%20development.&text=While%20it%27s%20easy%20to%20cheat,bar%20with%20a%20percentage%20progression). is a good resource to show what I mean